# IE 11 переопределение нативного метода

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

В коде определяю свой document.write = function(){*мой код*}
Затем делаю ajax запрос, ответ на этот запрос - js, который выполняется через window.eval. Внутри вернувшегося  js кода  идeт вызов document.write. Вот во всех браузерах кроме ie11 метод document.write переопределен и вызывается моя кастомная функция, кроме IE11. В нем как будто document.write свой и вызывается он, который перетирает мне всю страницу

Aбстрактный код

```
document.write = function(){
   // Мой код
}
```

`console.log(document.write)` - вижу мою функцию во всех браузерах(в том числе ие 11)

Делаю запрос(запрос **кроссдоменный**)

// обертка над XHR

```
ajax({
            url: url,
            async: false,
            callback: function (response) {
                console.log(document.write) // все браузеры кроме ИЕ11 выводят переопределенный метод.
                window.eval(response); // 
            }
        });
```

response в ответе - это js-код, который нужно выполнить.
Внутри этого js-кода вызывается мой переопреденный document.write.
Так вот во всех браузерах вызывается именно мой переопределенный метод. В ИЕ 11 вызывается нативный document.write.

Comment: Для чего вам нужно такое?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(document, "write", {value:...});`

Comment: Производственная необходимость

Comment: Object.defineProperty(document, "write", {value:...}) не работает